# I am using asp.net formview ,Date format changes when i host asp.net application in IIS running on local server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to enter dates into my database using asp.net form-view but my challenge is that the dates once entered like `04 jun 2018`, when I go to edit the template it will display as `4/06/2018 12:00:00 a.m.`

So the system will crash if I hit update, I have learnt that this 4/06/2018 12:00:00 a.m. is the cause for crush as the server will respond with datatype mismatch.

How can I display the date in my text box in edit template like `04/06/2018 12:00:00 am` as this is a valid date format?

It's working fine with local machine and the problem is when hosted it on Windows Server 2012.

Below is a textbox in my `EditItemTemplate`

```
 ApplicDate:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <asp:TextBox 
       ID="ApplicDateTxtBox"  
       EnableViewState="true"  runat="server"
       Text='<%# Bind("ApplicDate") %>' TextMode="singleline" />

 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
       ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" 
       runat="server" 
       ForeColor="red"
       ErrorMessage="Incorrect date format: example 15 feb 2018!" 
       ValidationExpression="^([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](19|20)\d\d\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\w{1}\.\w{1}\.$|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](19|20)\d\d\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\w{1}\.\w{1}\.$|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](19|20)\d\d\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\w{2}$|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s\w{3}\s(19|20)\d\d$"
       ControlToValidate="ApplicDateTxtBox">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date format with [BoundField.DataFormatString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_BoundField_DataFormatString)

For your case, it should be formatted as `G` for

> General date/time pattern (long time).

Specify this to FormView binding Field as

```
<%# Bind("<BINDING DATE COLUMN>", "{0:G}") %>
```

For your case,

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="ApplicDateTxtBox"  EnableViewState="true"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CheckDate", "{0:G}") %>' TextMode="singleline" />
```